# Mapbox GL-JS : Adding new tileset overlay under labels

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a tileset that I am loading into my map (map is called *topleftmap*). I want the city and other labels to load over the tiles, not under - sort of like in this example from Mapbox : https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/

How do I do this with tilesets? I have an external JS file I use to load in the tilesets like this :

```
topleftmapbox.addLayer({
    "id": "currentProduct",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": {
        "type": "raster",
        "tiles": ["tiles/" + productSelection + "/" + productLocation + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"],
        "minzoom": 8,
        "maxzoom": 10,
        "scheme": "tms",
        "tileSize": 256,

    }});
```

So of course that works fine, but the labels are UNDER the tiles. I have tried this below, (using the example from Mapbox) but it doesn't seem to work :

```
var layers = topleftmapbox.getStyle().layers;
    // Find the index of the first symbol layer in the map style
    var firstSymbolId;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
            firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
            break;
        }
    }

topleftmapbox.addLayer({
    "id": "currentProduct",
    "type": "raster",
    "source": {
        "type": "raster",
        "tiles": ["tiles/" + productSelection + "/" + productLocation + "/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"],
        "minzoom": 8,
        "maxzoom": 10,
        "scheme": "tms",
        "tileSize": 256,

    },firstSymbolId});
```

Lastly, here is an image showing what it looks like. My tiles are slightly transparent, but the labels should be bright white, like the ones away from the data. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything right. You just have a slight syntax mistake:

```
},firstSymbolId});
```

This should be:

```
}}, firstSymbolId);
```

Comment: That's what happens when I've been awake too long! Thanks for the second look.